# wso2 emm ios error 'MDM certificate is a required field. It cannot be empty.'

Tags: ios, wso2, mdm

I have installed my iOS features from the p2 repo.

I have my certificates ready to be uploaded but keep getting this error:

> MDM certificate is a required field. It cannot be empty.

The MDM Certificate field isn't empty. I've located the file and clicked it.  I've tried a few different browsers just in case but still the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by renaming the file from MDM_APNS.pfx to mdm.pfx - it allowed it to upload.

Comment: Cannot happens since we have uploaded the certificate with the exact same name. Anyway glad that its been fixed.